# Multiplying a List of Lists with a lists in F#

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

i have two lists i want to multiply them where each element in the lower list is multiplied with the corresponding list on the upper list on ziping it gives a clear picture but on multiplying it bugs

```
let list1 = [[0.10M;0.2M;0.35M;0.14M];[0.5M;0.60M;0.76M;0.18M];[0.19M;0.10M;0.51M;0.32M;];[0.13M;0.64M;0.95M;0.26M]]
let list2 = [0.1M;0.2M;0.3M;0.4M] 
let List = List.zip list1 list2 |> List.map(fun (x,y) -> x * y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two maps do the trick:

```
let list1 = [[0.10M;0.2M;0.35M;0.14M];[0.5M;0.60M;0.76M;0.18M];[0.19M;0.10M;0.51M;0.32M];[0.13M;0.64M;0.95M;0.26M]]

let list2 = [0.1M;0.2M;0.3M;0.4M] 

let listMult = list1 |> List.map (List.map2 (*) list2)
```